# I am Trying to get a value inside a span tag. The Span tag is Wrapped in an anchor tag which is wrapped a Div my code looks like as follows

Tags: jquery

**HTML**

```
 <div id="tab1">
       <ul class="tabs ui-helper">
        <li class="state ui-top">
            <a href="#tab1_2">
                <span>XYZ, ABC </span>
        </a>
         </li>
       </ul>
      </div>
```

**JS**

```
parentFrame.document.getElementById('tab1')
```

I am able to get the div

please help me how to navigate through div and get the value in the span

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EASY WAY**

Just add an id to the span like this.

```
<span id="spanTest">XYZ, ABC </span>
```

**Javascript**.

```
var spanTest = document.getElementById('spanTest').innerText;
console.log(spanTest)
```

**Jquery**

```
var spanTest = $('#spanTest').text();
console.log(spanTest)
```

**LITTLE BIT MORE COMPLEX**

**Jquery**

```
var  spanTest1 = $(this).find('span:first');
console.log("With Jquery " + spanTest1.text())
```

**Javascript**

```
var spanTest = document.getElementsByClassName('ui-top'),
    firstEl = spanTest[0].lastElementChild;
console.log("with pure Javascript " + firstEl.firstElementChild.innerText)
```

Here is the working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ar02xdr9/4/)

Comment: I would love to add Id to the span, but that's some thing which is generic.is their a way to do that without adding Id to span?

Comment: just added a new code and jsFiddle if this answer help you feel free to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: '$(parentFrame.document.getElementById('tab1')).find("span:last").text()'

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery, you can select it like this

```
var a = $("#tab1").first("span");
```

Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/m553z88j/1/

Comment: Thanks guys finally it worked '$(parentFrame.document.getElementById('tab1')).find("span:last").text()'